# How to upload Magento patch to root directory?

Tags: magento, patch

I am not a developer.

Today when I login admin panel, a message pop up telling me to download/upload Magento CE Patches **SUPEE-5344 and SUPEE-1533**

And I found this tutorial [Magento CE Patches tutorial](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html#apply) But I don't know what path to upload the `.SH` files. I know they provided an Example, `/var/www/html/magento.`but I don't have this www file should I create one?

Since I don't know what to do so I uploaded on `cgi-bin` folder. And I am not sure is working or not.

Please help me with this.

Best Regards

Comment: If you're not a developer, I'd suggest that you employ one to install this patch for you - the chance of you breaking your web server is too high to mess around with things you don't know about in this case. There are multiple steps required and a basic knowledge of web server systems/Linux is required to install this patch successfully

Answer (score 0):

The patches should be uploaded and executed from Magento root directory. If you have Magento installed, the directory should exist already. This is the typical content of this directory:

```
$ ls -1
api.php
app
cron.php
cron.sh
downloader
errors
favicon.ico
includes
index.php
index.php.sample
install.php
js
lib
mage
media
PATCH_SUPEE-4829_EE_1.14.1.0_v1.sh
pkginfo
shell
skin
var
```

Comment: Yes I do have Magento installed, so I don't have to create any files? All I have to do is throw it in the Files right?

Comment: Yes, into the same directory with all Magento files.

Answer (score 0):

Upload it to the root of your magento installation. If your not confident with ssh i would ask a web developer to do this work for you, as potentially you could break everything.